# Hibernate Configuration from EJB module returns illegalStateException in my EAR (MVN2 + Spring MVC 4 + Hibernate 4 + MySQL) using annotation

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, annotations, ear

I've executed **MVN2 + Wildfly 10 + Spring MVC 4 + Hibernate 4 + MySQL using annotation** same like the example from the below link **in the war module, its working fine**. Not working in the EJB module if I place all the core logic. I'm using Eclipse(latest), and JDK 8.

**http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/**

I moved the **hibernateconfiguration, service, dao, repository**, to the EJB module in my EAR project, it's not at all launching the application. Getting following exception on server start-up.

I've been trying this for a month in various ways. Getting error always.

Please help me. Thanks in advance...

```
    23:10:09,229 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 168) Context initialization failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.sakthi.core.config.HibernateConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:384)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:231)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.sakthi.imsx.core.config.HibernateConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13c7c533 is not an enhanced class
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:621)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerStaticCallbacks(Enhancer.java:594)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:374)
    ... 24 more

23:10:09,229 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 168) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./imsx-web: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./imsx-web: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.sakthi.imsx.core.config.HibernateConfiguration
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.sakthi.imsx.core.config.HibernateConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:384)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:263)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:231)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:526)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.sakthi.imsx.core.config.HibernateConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$13c7c533 is not an enhanced class
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:621)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerStaticCallbacks(Enhancer.java:594)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:374)
    ... 24 more
```

**HibernateConfiguration.java**

```
package com.sakthi.core.config;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.sakthi.core.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "root");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "root");
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }

}
```

Comment: Really using Maven 2?

Comment: @Khmarbaise, I'm sorry dude. I'm new to maven. I just have created as a maven project in eclipse, and selected wildfly-javaee-ear-blank-archtype and created the EAR project. But when I explored some blogs, it has been specified as maven 2. Even in the same example in the link, specified as maven 3. So maybe it is maven 3. The thing is, it is working fine if I'm not using the hibernateconfiguration and trying to call service or dao methods without error. But, using hibernateconfiguration, if I try to connect, its not working. Getting the above exception.

Comment: I'm using Maven 4 I guess. My pom has the project tag like `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">`.

Comment: You wrote `...MVN2..` which made me unsure if you are really using Maven 2. The pom contains schema version 4.0.0 but what is most important here is the entry `<modelVersion>...</modelVersion>` in your pom file..Furthermore based on the given reference to that tutorial you should use Maven 3.X...

Comment: Hi. I have tried in maven 3 version also. Actually, the issue here is not because of maven. The example is working fine if I use all the classes in web module alone. Issue is, If I move the hibernate configuration to `ejb` module, server is not starting up. It gives `Context initialization failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException`. I tried it without hibernateconfiguration and db calling methods. Then, I'm able to reach those core class methods and logs are getting printed. The issue is, what is the solution for hibernateconfiguration to be initialized properly.